# Can I put an ongoing project on my resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume, internship

I am currently a junior in college studying computer science. While I have a couple of projects on my resume, the project I am working on now is a much "stronger" project. About half the semester has passed so I do have a good amount of work completed on it. I'd like to put it on my resume because I think it will look good to potential internship employers. Should I put it on my resume?

Comment: Just stop. It's not a duplicate. An unfinished project is nothing like an ongoing project. They are only tangentially similar.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I meant to say cancelled but deleting and reposting that comment would be too snarky, even for me. My point remains though that they're similar but by no means a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I think your reasoning is sound and it can't really hurt anything. Unless there's a compelling reason not to, go for it. Many people put projects (completed and ongoing) on their resumes so you're not alone.

Answer (score 0):

I say absolutely include it on your resume, provided you state that it is ongoing and how much of it is completed.